# Проблема с использованием spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, ооп, namespace

Делаю сейчас для себя проект, хочу разобраться в автозагрузке и неймспейсах.
Есть следующая структура проекта:

[image: структура проекта]
Получаю следующие проблемы.

1. Когда перехожу в тестовый файл где есть такой код:

```
use App\App;
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Core/App.php');
$a = new App;
$a::getView('test');
```

Получаю следующую ошибку

```
Warning: require_once(/volume1/web/tasks\App\Classes\DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/tasks/Core/App.php on line 12 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/volume1/web/tasks\App\Classes\DB.php' (include_path='.:/var/packages/PEAR/target') in /volume1/web/tasks/Core/App.php on line 12
```

Как я подозреваю - проблема в слешах (у меня Win10, сменить на линукс не получится).

2. в коде подключения к базе данных при использовании пространства имен получаю эту ошибку. По идее использования автолодера должно было ее решить, нет?
   [image: ошибка при использовании namespace]
   Композером практически не умею пользоваться, хотя читал что эту проблему можно решить с помощью него. Но так как проект не особо большой я хотел бы понять как вообще работает автозагрузка и неймспейсы на практике, не думаю что композер стоит разворачивать ради 5-6 классов, да и не умею особо им пользоваться

Автозагрузка идет в классе App, код ниже

```
namespace App;
use App\Classes\DB as DB;
use App\Route\Route as Routs;
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

class App{
        function __construct(){
            spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
                require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$class_name . '.php');
            });
            self::InitDB();
            self::InitRouting();
            // self::Init();
            // self::test();
        }
        static function InitRouting(){
            $route = new Routs;
            return $route;
        }
        static function InitDB(){
            $db = new DB;
            return $db;
        }
        static function getView($view){
            $r = Routs::base_path_route();
            $str = $r['views'].$view;
            return $str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот тут не понял, я же на тестовой странице подключаю этот класс

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Core/App.php');

По моей логике если я подключаю класс в котором идет автозагрузка то со всем остальным не должно быть проблем... или как?

Comment: Ну окей, это я проглядел. Но дальше то что происходит - хочешь подключить файл с таким же именем как у класса (`App\Classes\DB`), а папка `App` есть у тебя? Я вижу только `Core`.

Comment: а разве неймспейс должен соответствовать папке? ок перепишу сейчас

Comment: Ну ты ищешь файл по пути "App\Classes\DB.php", App - это папка, где она?

Comment: заменил App на  Core, теперь все выглядит  примерно так
App.php
namespace Core;
use Core\Classes\DB as DB;
use Core\Route\Route as Routs;

Route.php
namespace Core\Route;

DB.php
namespace Core\Classes;

И соответственно на тестовой странице  я сделал так:
use Core\App;
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Core/App.php');
$a = new App;
$a::getView('test');

не работает

Comment: Ошибка
Warning: require_once(/volume1/web/tasks/Core\Classes\DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web/tasks/Core/App.php on line 12 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/volume1/web/tasks/Core\Classes\DB.php' (include_path='.:/var/packages/PEAR/target') in /volume1/web/tasks/Core/App.php on line 12

Comment: Надо разобраться со слешами. Почему подключаешь один файл как `/Core/App.php`, а другой как `Core\Classes\DB.php`?

Comment: Вот со слешами я сам не понимаю почему так
Ведь когда неймспейс пишешь там юзается \ слеш
А когда require там надо обратный слеш.
и соответсвенно у меня в автолоаде в App.php идет разнобой, а как его поправить я не знаю

Comment: `str_replace` одно на другое?

Comment: Вроде как отработало, но теперь вторая проблема с mysqli

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109190/discussion-between--and-u-mulder).

Answer (score 0):

Короче в чем была проблема... 
По первому пункту @u_mudler подсказал решение:

```
$str = str_replace("\\", "/", $str);
require_once ($str);
```

По второму пункту нагуглил объяснение\решение этой проблемы.
Надо было обращаться к глобальному пространству имен, то есть

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli('ccc', 'ccc', 'ccsc', 'ccd'); //correct
```

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli('ccc', 'ccc', 'ccsc', 'ccd'); // this not correct if used namespace
```